# apt upgrade breaks python-rpi.gpio

Tags: raspbian, python, apt, update, failure

There seems to be an issue in the Raspbian repository since around the start of March. My Pi running motion stopped working around then - probably due to an `apt update` I did around that time. Not able to repair the installation, I decided to reflash and reinstall. So the following operations:

```
reflash SD card with latest download of Raspbian Lite
enable ssh using raspi-config
reboot
apt update
apt upgrade
```

results in the following

```
 ...
Adding 'diversion of /boot/fixup4x.dat to /usr/share/rpikernelhack/fixup4x.dat by rpikernelhack'
Adding 'diversion of /boot/LICENCE.broadcom to /usr/share/rpikernelhack/LICENCE.broadcom by rpikernelhack'
Unpacking raspberrypi-bootloader (1.20210303-1) over (1.20210108-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../30-python-rpi.gpio_0.7.0-0.1~bpo10+4_armhf.deb ...
ImportError: No module named site
dpkg: warning: old python-rpi.gpio package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
ImportError: No module named site
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-Xp8mOe/30-python-rpi.gpio_0.7.0-0.1~bpo10+4_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 new python-rpi.gpio package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
ImportError: No module named site
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed python-rpi.gpio package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Preparing to unpack .../31-rpi.gpio-common_0.7.0-0.1~bpo10+4_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking rpi.gpio-common:armhf (0.7.0-0.1~bpo10+4) over (0.7.0-0.1~bpo10+3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../32-raspberrypi-sys-mods_20210310_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking raspberrypi-sys-mods (20210310) over (20201026) ...
Preparing to unpack .../33-raspi-config_20210212_all.deb ...
Unpacking raspi-config (20210212) over (20201108) ...
Preparing to unpack .../34-rpi-eeprom_11.12-1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking rpi-eeprom (11.12-1) over (11.1-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../35-sudo_1.8.27-1+deb10u3_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking sudo (1.8.27-1+deb10u3) over (1.8.27-1+deb10u2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../36-unzip_6.0-23+deb10u2_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking unzip (6.0-23+deb10u2) over (6.0-23+deb10u1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-Xp8mOe/30-python-rpi.gpio_0.7.0-0.1~bpo10+4_armhf.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

so I ran `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and got

```
...
Setting up firmware-libertas (1:20190114-1+rpt11) ...
Setting up libisccc161:armhf (1:9.11.5.P4+dfsg-5.1+deb10u3) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-rpi.gpio:
 python-rpi.gpio depends on rpi.gpio-common (= 0.7.0-0.1~bpo10+3); however:
  Version of rpi.gpio-common:armhf on system is 0.7.0-0.1~bpo10+4.

dpkg: error processing package python-rpi.gpio (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up openssl (1.1.1d-0+deb10u5+rpt2) ...
Setting up raspi-config (20210212) ...
...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-rpi.gpio
```

Does this suggest that the latest release of `rpi.gpio-common:armhf` is incompatible with `python-rpi.gpio`? Is there a workaround or can we just never `apt upgrade` our Pis if we want to use utilities that depend on Python... which is most of them.

Comment: Very unusual for a fresh install to fail.  Are you sure you made no other changes?

Comment: Something has gone wrong. I suggest you repeat the installation. RPi.GPIO hasn't changed since July 2019 (for Buster) and is already included - no need to upgrade! Maybe you need a new SD Card - they do wear out.